# The image of the J-homomorphism of the tangent bundle of the sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, whitehead-product

Consider the J-homomorphism $\pi_{n-1}(SO(n))\to \pi_{2n-1}(S^n)$ and $\tau_{S^n}:S^{n-1}\to SO(n)$ to be the adjoint of the classifying map of the tangent bundle of the standard sphere. In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970425), Wall claims that $J(\tau_{S^n})=[id_n,id_n]$ where $id_n$ is the identity map of $S^n$. How can one see this?

Comment: In principle I suppose you could also make a direct argument using framed cobordism.  The pre-image of a point under the map $[id_n,id_n]$ is a standard linking pair $S^{n-1} \sqcup S^{n-1} \subset S^{2n-1}$, each trivially framed.  The classifying map for the tangent bundle of $S^n$ can be described explicitly as a composite of two mirror reflections (with one map varying).  Put those two together with the Hopf construction and that should suffice.

Comment: The relation follows from the discussion in Section 2 of James' "On the iterated suspension''.

Answer (score 12):

There is probably more than one good way to look at this. I'll point out that $\tau_{S^n}$ is the boundary of a generator of
$$
\pi_n(SO(n+1),SO(n))\cong \pi_n S^n.
$$
The map
$$
\pi_jS^n\cong \pi_j(SO(n+1),SO(n))\to \pi_{j+n}(\Omega S^{n+1},S^n)
$$
is an isomorphism, not just for $j=n$ but for $j<2n-1$. And the attaching map for the $2n$-cell in the James model for $\Omega S^{n+1}$ is that Whitehead product.

Comment: Great answer. Just a question: is there a reference for the connectivity of the map that you mentioned?

Comment: You can get it from the James model and the Blakers-Massey triad connectivity theorem (a.k.a. homotopy excision), and I suppose that someone did so about 75 years ago, but I don't have a reference. You can also prove it using functor calculus (maybe Weiss's orthogonal calculus). There is also an indirect proof using surgery theory!

Comment: The accepted answer of [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247845/is-the-j-homomorphism-compatible-with-the-ehp-sequence) question gives an argument for the connectivity of this map.